# How to get correct ticklabs in a 3d-scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, scatter3d

Please see this example. Look at `y` axis. The data there has only two levels: `1` and `2`. But in the plot 6 tickmarks drawn on that axis. How could I fix that. The `x` axis has the same problem.

The data

```
   extra group ID
1    0.7     1  1
2   -1.6     1  2
3   -0.2     1  3
4   -1.2     1  4
5   -0.1     1  5
6    3.4     1  6
7    3.7     1  7
8    0.8     1  8
9    0.0     1  9
10   2.0     1 10
11   1.9     2  1
12   0.8     2  2
13   1.1     2  3
14   0.1     2  4
15  -0.1     2  5
16   4.4     2  6
17   5.5     2  7
18   1.6     2  8
19   4.6     2  9
20   3.4     2 10
```

The script

```
require('mise')
require('scatterplot3d')
mise()  # clear the workspace

# example data
print(sleep)

# plot it
scatterplot3d(x=sleep$ID,
              x.ticklabs=levels(sleep$ID),
              y=sleep$group,
              y.ticklabs=levels(sleep$group),
              z=sleep$extra)
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
scatterplot3d(x=sleep$ID, y=sleep$extra, z=sleep$group, lab.z = c(1, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefere that `scatterplot3d(x=sleep$ID, z=sleep$extra, y=sleep$group, lab=c(10, 2), type='h')`. But your answer gave the right hint. Thanks!